# Are different questions that share an answer duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

I often see a question closed as a duplicate of another when it is *clearly* a different question, because the other question happens to have an answer that can be applied to the first one.

For example "how do I change the desktop background on one screen?", it would get marked as duplicate of "how do I change my desktop background" because one of the answers on that question *happens* to also explain how to do it for multiple screens.

This seems wrong. The description SO gives for duplicates is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." not "An answer is available on another question.".

Furthermore closing that question means nobody else can add answers, which they wouldn't have added to the older question because it wasn't asking for them!

Why do Stack Overflow users seem to close *questions* as duplicate because the *answers* are duplicate? It is the questions that are being declared as duplicates, not the answers right?

Comment: Most of the time, yes, but there is room for this to not be the case. One simply needs to edit their question to adequately differentiate it from the other.

Comment: The description I see for duplicates (both logged in and logged out) isn't what you state, it's *"This question already has an answer here:"*. That is subtly, but importantly, different to what you state it says; it doesn't state that it was been *asked* before.

Comment: @ThomA might be the different message that a OP gets on one of their own questions.

Comment: I don't see how "how do I change the desktop background on one screen?" is not a sub-task of "how do I change my desktop background", From the titles, the two seem clearly related and asking about essentially the same thing. The latter being the more general task of the two. A *good* answer to the second question would explain how to change the background on all screens to be the same or how to change individual screen's background. Or am I missing something? Overall, I don't get what this question here is trying to say - is it about actually different questions or just different wording?

Comment: I get the same message for questions I've asked as well, @cafce25 , so that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: "Or am I missing something?" - yes you are. You say "a good answer" would answer the question that wasn't actually asked. Answers do not need to answer any more than was asked. Sometimes they do, but they don't have to.

Comment: @ThomA it definitely is [in the system as description of reason type 101](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1170960/close-reason-types)

Comment: @ThomA: Try to close a question as duplicate. You will see the message I quoted.

Comment: There is indeed a mismatch in wording between the close dialog and the dupe closure header

Comment: @Timmmm we're here to provide "detailed, high-quality answers". Not just the bare minimum.  So, an answer to the second question that explains how to change the background of individual monitors is certainly not unexpected and unneeded. Asking how to change backgrounds does not preclude one wanting to change to *different* backgrounds one each monitor. Such activity is still "changing backgrounds". The same way as "tying a shoe" and "tying both shoes" are not two distinct skills one has to master.

Comment: A different question arriving at an exact duplicate answer doesn't produce a new answer, it just provides the same answer to a different scenario. Pointing that question to the other question where the answer already exists provides the same value, as long as there are no *better* solutions to the different question that aren't also *better* on the existing.

Comment: @Timmmm I close questions as duplicates, I don't see that message.

Comment: If reading the answers to question A will give you what you need for question B, then closing as a duplicate is useful because it gives you (and anyone else) the information you're looking for. What is the downside?

Comment: What they're presumably actually asking about: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77809410/3001761

Comment: "Also note that this question contains the answer but it is very clearly NOT a duplicate question, even though one of its answers also answers this question. Therefore I'm re-posting this for Google." That’s pretty much exactly what duplicates are there for.

Comment: *This seems wrong. The description SO gives for duplicates is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." not "An answer is available on another question."* Yeah... that's Stack Overflow. It doesn't explain itself very clearly most of the time. It doesn't matter what you want the truth to be, the only thing that matters is what the majority of people will choose to do in response to a question based on the commonly agreed interpretation of the rules. You're best off to learn what the consensus is rather than try to interpret yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Roughly: it depends. A good rule of thumb is that if you have to already know the answer to the source question to think that it's a duplicate of the target, it's not a duplicate.

In this example, that does sound like a duplicate: both are fundamentally about changing the desktop background. However, you could imagine truly unrelated questions with the same answer, such as (continuing with general-computing examples) "How do I fix lagginess in Windows?" and "How do I reboot a Windows computer?". These wouldn't be duplicates, even if the answer to the first question is "reboot your computer."

Comment: It's easy to come up with trivial counterexamples like that but I'm not sure I've ever seen one (hypothetical or otherwise) where the non-duplicates are *also* good Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery [zipping arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856717) and [transposing a 2D array/matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17428587) are both tasks that can be done via the same code. However, I'd argue they aren't duplicates as the two concepts and especially *why* you'd use them are different.

Comment: @VLAZ *if your 2d array is represented as a nested structure*, then the task is equivalent to zipping (for the "special" case of rectangular data, which doesn't really matter - it's the *other* cases where there's something interesting to say). *Knowing* that the task is equivalent to zipping is the key insight to the problem, because there are standard approaches for that; and nothing else makes sense to do unless you need an in-place operation (which *would* IMO make it a different question).

Answer (score 5):

Does question A getting closed as a duplicate of question B somehow limit the ability of question A to be adequately answered?

Put another way... if there's a particular problem with the answers in question B that cause them to not be adequate for question A, that should be pointed out in question A so that answerers can actually address the problem (or misconception!) that the OP has that is driving them to be unable to use the answers in question B.

Avoiding linking questions just because there's some subtle difference that may never matter risks slowing down the route for people reaching the solution they need. The link only needs to be broken when there's a difference that is actually known to be important.

---

Specific to your example, I can imagine a scenario where there might be a more convenient way to solve the problem one at a time vs all at once that would also be inconvenient as an answer to changing them all at once. I don't know how I would approach that to be honest. An answer on the "multiple desktops" question that only changed one that  would be an inefficient answer if tweaked to "work" for multiple wouldn't get much traction. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Creating a new question just for this one scenario... may never gain traction either if there's no reason the rest of the answers on question B wouldn't still be relevant to it. At best it'd just get closed as a duplicate after being answered, leaving the answer accessible while still pointing to the rest of the answers. Generally the former would net you more views.